# What is the difference with the _KHR image layouts in Vulkan?

Tags: vulkan

When specifying an image layout there are optional variants of the same image layout with a _KHR suffix  on them, such as:

```
VkImageLayout::VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL
VkImageLayout::VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL_KHR
VkImageLayout::VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMA
VkImageLayout::VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL_KHR
```

Why are there two different types of these, and others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, there is no difference between the KHR-suffixed enum constant and the same non-KHR-suffixed enum constant. That is to say, their *values* are equal.

It simply depends on when constants (and also functions and structs) get introduced into a core Vulkan version specification. That's when the KHR suffix is removed and (in this case) simply aliases to the KHR-suffixed constants.

These particular constants were first introduced in the Vulkan extension `VK_KHR_separate_depth_stencil_layouts` which made it into *core* in Vulkan 1.2.

Whether you make use of the KHR-suffixed constant or the core constant is then mostly to communicate in your code (to readers of your code) whether you use/enable the extension `VK_KHR_separate_depth_stencil_layouts` or whether you do use at least Vulkan 1.2.